# arcgis union python error

Tags: python, union, analysis, loops, arcgis

Trying to loop through multiple spatial extents to create 17 unions of 4 different layers.

I'm running ArcGIS Desktop 10.0, ArcInfo (advanced).

```
Gridnums = range(1,18)
for i in Gridnums:
    #vis6class = ws + "/" + "TVvis6class_G" + str(i)
    inList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*ProcGrid_"+str(i), "")
    print "inList: " + str(inList)
    arcpy.Union_analysis([InList], ws + "/" + "TVvis6class_G" + str(i))
    print "Union completed for Grid " + str(i)
    arcpy.AddField_management(vis6class, "Object", "TEXT", 10)
    arcpy.AddField_management(vis6class, "Revert", "SHORT")
    rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(vis6class)
    for row in rows:
        row.Revert = 0
        if row.Road == 1:
            row.Object = Road
            rows.updateRow(row)
        elif row.Water == 1:
            row.Object = Water
            rows.updateRow(row)
        elif row.Building == 1:
            row.Object = Building
            rows.updateRow(row)
        else:
            row.Object = row.Landcover
            rows.updateRow(row)
```

Error Code (not very helpful):

> inList: [u'Road_ProcGrid_1', u'FPs_S_ProcGrid_1', u'er_di_ProcGrid_1',
>   u'TV_v_ProcGrid_1']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\Projects\TV\01_Python\LandCover\LC_2_Vector_Tile_6class_091312.py",
>   line 48, in 
>       arcpy.Union_analysis([InList], ws + "/" + "TVvis6class_G" + str(i))   File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 483, in Union
>       raise e RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool

I know this is programming forum over ArcGIS, but I've posted onto the esri forums as well, with lots of views but little feedback.
The tool itself runs, if I manually select each dataset for a particular extent, so the problem has to be in the coding.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [InList] as an input instead of just 'inList' without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ArcGIS online help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000s000000), the `Union_analysis` function requires a class as second argument, when you're passing a string. Try passing an object instead.